# Prove that if there is$f'(x_{0})$ then also exist a symmetrical derivative $f'_{sym}= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x _{0} +h)-f(x _{0}-h)}{h} $

Tags: real-analysis

**My try**
$$f'(x_{0})=\lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x _{0} +h)-f(x _{0})}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0}  (\frac{f(x _{0} +h)-f(x _{0})}{2h}+\frac{f(x _{0})-f(x _{0}-h)}{2h}=\lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x _{0} +h)-f(x _{0}-h)}{2h}= f'_{sym}$$

So I proved this task but I have one doubt - showing that $ f '(x_ {0}) = f' _ {sym} $ is also proof that $ f '_ {sym} $ exists, or should I additionally prove it?

Comment: It's fib=ne, you proved existence and equality in one stroke.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{f(x _{0} +h)-f(x _{0}-h)}{h}=\frac{f(x _{0} +h)-f(x_{0})}{h}+\frac{f(x _{0} -h)-f(x _{0})}{-h} \to 2f'(x_0)$ as $h \to 0$.